# Restrict commit in git stash by allowing few users to commit to Master

Tags: locking, bitbucket-server, unlock

Currently we have TFS and use this feature of only allowing certain users to checkin after review and testing. Our company is adopting devops model and moving towards Atlassian STASH and this tool doesn't have this feature readily available. Anyone has implemented it?

Comment: the git admin can restrict who can commit where. github offers easy configuration for that too. some people use gerrit to only allow reviewed commits on the main repo

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean Atlassian Stash, not git stash?

If so, you can use [branch permissions to enforce a workflow](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Using+branch+permissions) that only allows certain users to write to a branch (such as master), and/or to allow changes only via pull requests.

Combined with [pull request settings](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Checks+for+merging+pull+requests) that require a minimum number of approvals you can achieve a strict change management workflow as desired.

Now, what I just said does require slightly different thinking. Your wording implied a review and test should happen before *checkin*. With git, people can and should work on branches that are committed *and* pushed to the central repository. It is before *merge* that review and testing takes place.

As an aside, these features aren't exactly pre-requisites for a "devops model" (some may in fact argue the opposite), but I can see how judicious use of workflow settings (branch permissions and pull request settings) could play a part.

Disclosure: I work for Atlassian